# TypeScript higer order React component typings

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to write typings for the native ads part of https://github.com/callstack/react-native-fbads. I have thus far come up with the following:

```
declare module 'react-native-fbads' {
    import { Component } from 'react';

    export class NativeAdsManager {
        constructor(placementId: string, numberOfAdsToRequest: number);
    }

    export interface NativeAd {
        icon?: string;
        coverImage?: string;
        title?: string;
        subtitle?: string;
        decription?: string;
        callToActionText?: string;
        socialContext?: string;
    }

    interface IWithAd {
        nativeAd: NativeAd;
    }

    interface IWithManger {
        adsManager: NativeAd;
    }

    export function withNativeAd<T, S>(comp: Component<T & IWithAd, S>): Component<T & IWithManger, S>;
}
```

But when I try to use it with a component like the following:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { NativeAd, withNativeAd } from 'react-native-fbads';

interface IProps {
    myProp: number;
    nativeAd: NativeAd;
}

class AdComponent extends React.Component<IProps> {
    public render() {
        return (
            <View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default withNativeAd(AdComponent);
```

I get the following error:

```
Argument of type 'typeof AdComponent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component<IWithAd, {}>'.
  Property 'setState' is missing in type 'typeof AdComponent'
```

The important thing here is that "withNativeAd" should be typed as a function that takes a React component with some properties + a "nativeAd" property and returns another React component that has those properties - "nativeAd" + "adsManager". Obviously I am doing wrong but I have no idea what the correct way is and the errors are not helping.

EDIT:

So changing to the following with ComponentClass:

```
declare module 'react-native-fbads' {
    import { ComponentClass } from 'react';

    export class NativeAdsManager {
        constructor(placementId: string, numberOfAdsToRequest: number);
    }

    export interface NativeAd {
        icon?: string;
        coverImage?: string;
        title?: string;
        subtitle?: string;
        decription?: string;
        callToActionText?: string;
        socialContext?: string;
    }

    interface IWithAd {
        nativeAd: NativeAd;
    }

    interface IWithManger {
        adsManager: NativeAd;
        nativeAd: undefined;
    }

    export function withNativeAd<P>(comp: ComponentClass<P & IWithAd>): ComponentClass<P & IWithManger>;
}
```

Makes the previous error go away but complains that I am not assigning anything to "nativeAd" when creating an instance of the wrapped object. The typings should instead require only "adsManager" not "nativeAd" because the wrapped component generates "nativeAd" with the "adsManager".

Comment: Can you provide a runnable example

Answer (score 0):

I found using `react.componentClass` as the wrapped component input fixed the error for me when I had a similar problem:

```
  export const withNativeAd = <TProps, TState>(WrappedComponent: React.ComponentClass<IWithAd> ): React.ComponentClass<IWithAd>  => {
    return class extends React.Component<IWithAd, TState> {
        render() {
            return (
                <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
            )
        }
    }
}
```